# Don't able to run flutter code due to Firebase error

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
Running "flutter pub get" in state_login...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 8 in 64 seconds...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 9 in 64 seconds...
Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 10 in 64 seconds...
Because state_login depends on firebase_messaging ^20.0.1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in state_login...
pub get failed (1; Because state_login depends on firebase_messaging ^20.0.1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving       
failed.)
```

Comment: Please share your `pubspec.yaml`, `build,gradle` (app & project level) and your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Help us help you by providing the information required to reproduce the problem/situation.

Comment: now it is not required @Alok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of firebase_messaging. The latest version is `firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16`
Tell me if it works.

Comment: Yeah it worded @Adarsh Balu

Comment: Happy to help !